# Equality of matrix of trigonometric functions in n-power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry

Could you help me please and give some tips on how should I start solving this problem. How can one prove, that this equation is right, when n from $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\alpha$ is from $\mathbb{R}$?

$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \alpha  & -\sin \alpha\\ 
\sin \alpha  & \cos \alpha 
\end{pmatrix}^{n}  = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos n\alpha  & -\sin n\alpha\\ 
\sin n\alpha  & \cos n\alpha 
\end{pmatrix}$

Should I use induction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Accepting answers is easy. Just click on the empty tick mark to the left of the most helpful answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, induction should work. ${}$

Comment: Thank you for response. 
Can you give me please some more tips on how should I move on? I used to prove by induction when n is from natural numbers, so I knew, where the start is. I'm a little bit confused by integers.

Comment: First prove it by induction for positive $n$. Then either prove it by induction for negative $n$, or use what you know about the form of the inverse of a 2 x 2 matrix to prove the negative result from the positive. And please learn how to accept answers, or else people will stop giving any.

Comment: Thank you. I've done it per induction. 
Will try later to do it by "positive result --> negative result".

Answer (score 3):

You can also see that your matrix is the rotation matrix of α radians. Hence, if you rotate n times α radians you would end up with effectively a rotation of nα radians. Little tricky but slightly shorter.

Comment: Thank you response. 
I think, I'm not "ripe" enough at the moment to do it this way. But I'll come back to this method later =)